# Django return objects that are attributes of queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following query that returns a list of Connection objects:

```
Connection.objects.filter(group_id=self.id)
```

This is the connection class:

```
class Connection(models.Model):
   contact = models.OneToOneField(Contact)
   *** some extra attributes ***
```

Now is it possible to get all contact objects in the query? I tried:

```
Connection.objects.filter(group_id=self.id).values_list('contact')
```

This returns all the id's, so I could query each object separately, but I don't think that that is efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Contact.objects.filter(connection__group_id=self.id)
```